# How do I put the HEAD back to its previous position after reset?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset, git-amend

I wanted to amend a commit message from two commits ago, so I did:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1
$ git commit --amend -m "Revised commit message"
```

Now how do I get HEAD back to where it was before I `git reset`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just `git add -a` to stage all the changes you `reset` and then `git commit` them, but I think you're going about this all wrong.

If you just want to fix an earlier commit message, you could do the following:

- `git rebase -i HEAD~2`

This will rebase your last two commits of the branch, so no code will be changed. Once you do this, you will get a vim (or whatever your default editor is) screen that looks something like this:

```
pick 2a86f99 commit before that you want to fix
pick 09c407a commit that is at HEAD
```

- change the `pick` in the commit you want to fix to `reword`:

  reword  2a86f99 commit before that you want to fix
  pick 09c407a commit that is at HEAD
- Save and quit (`:wq` in vim). git will rebase these changes and pause in an editor of the commit message you want to fix. Fix it, save, and quit, and you should be set to go.